# Storing output of a iterating function into unique tables KDB+/Q

Tags: kdb

I have a query function of the format:

`function:{[x] select Y from table1 where date=x}`

I want to iterate this function across all days stored in a separate table, like so

`function each (select distinct date from table2)`

and store every iteration into it's own, unique table. For example, if the first iteration was for 2021.11.10, all 'Y' values from table1 on that date are stored in a table named 'a', for the next iteration for date 2021.11.12, it goes to a table named 'b', or something like that. How can I do this?

Comment: For clarification, running that function as is generates a 'length error, since the result is a table for each iteration. Hence the need for a place to put each iteration's table somewhere

Comment: I just saw this clarification - you're getting a 'length error because you are passing in each item of the output of a `select` statement. In this case each element is a dictionary. If you use the `exec` form I have in my answer it will avoid this error. You could also change your `=` to an `in` to make it work in it's current form (although this won't work in all cases).

Comment: Having each output table be its own variable isn't really a good idea to be honest. It could be a dictionary of dates to outputs like Matt suggested below.  Or you could use `group` or `xgroup` to group the table using the date col (if it's as simple a function as your example suggests).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume the following tables:

```
q)t1:([]date:.z.d + 0 0 0 1 1 1;a:1 2 3 4 5 6)
q)t2:([]date:.z.d+0 1)
```

then you could do something like:

```
q)function:{[x;y] x set select from t1 where date=y}
q)function'[`a`b;exec distinct date from t2]
`a`b
q)show a
date       a
------------
2021.11.10 1
2021.11.10 2
2021.11.10 3
q)show b
date       a
------------
2021.11.11 4
2021.11.11 5
2021.11.11 6
```

If you wanted to make it a bit more dynamic then you could also do something like:

```
q)function:{[x] (`$"tab",string[x] except ".") set select from t1 where date=x}
q)
q)
q)function each exec distinct date from t2
`tab20211110`tab20211111
q)show tab20211110
date       a
------------
2021.11.10 1
2021.11.10 2
2021.11.10 3
q)show tab20211111
date       a
------------
2021.11.11 4
2021.11.11 5
2021.11.11 6
```

The above creates new tables named for each date (we remove the "." from the resulting names as they could be confused for q's `.` operator)

Comment: I would probably approach this in the more dynamic way too but with a dictionary of dates to tables